Any suggestions on how to model something like a tungsten carbide bur?
Would appreciate any suggestions on how to model a tungsten carbide bur.

Being a Blender noob I tried to start with extruding a star-shaped curve, adding edge loops and twisting the model with proportional editing, but I'm stuck here. I don't how to make the cross cut maintaining good topology. Thanks!





How much resolution (density or poly count) would you be aiming for ? I'm working on a procedural GN solution but it would be quite low-poly, at least for now.

I'm not expert enough in Blender to implement this, but from manufacturing perspective that is made with two kind of cuts: one shallow clockwise spiral cut and multiple steep counterclockwise spiral cuts. I think screw modifier could be used to create the cuts and boolean modifier would be used to remove them from the base shape.

Idk about the poly count. for now I'm trying to achieve as much photorealism as possible to later use it in marketing purposes

booleans is what I thought first because actually I couln't come up with any other solution. the problem with booleans is to properly integrate the cuts into the basic mesh to maintain proper topology which is extremely difficult for me now at my level of Blender skills. so I hoped there might be some alternative solution

You could try this way even though it won't be accurate as the segment seems to change from bottom to top:
Model your segment:

Array on X and Z:

Give it a Simple Deform modifier, Bend mode on Z, and also a Weld modifier so that the first and last segments merge:

Give it another Simple Deform modifier, Taper mode, on Z and with an empty as Origin:

Give it a third Simple Deform modifier, Twist mode, on Z and with the same empty as Origin:


yes, they do change. the teeth get smaller closer to the top. but most importantly the cross cut on the bur comes with an angle which still makes it difficult to replicate with your approach. but thank you anyway
